Python Executable to Modify Excel Files
I have a python script that generates and saves barcode pngs (using barcode-python) to a folder based on data extracted from an Excel spreadsheet (using pandas). The general issue I'm having is in user friendliness. I don't want everyone who uses the spreadsheet to have to install python and learn how to run a script. I've been trying a bunch of different ways to make this work, but I'm currently leaning towards using PyInstaller to create an executable that can generate the barcodes without python being installed on the users machine.
I've set it up using the default PyInstaller folder method and it seems to work fine. I would prefer to have a more organized and concise approach using --onefile, but when trying to implement the executable in one file, I am struggling to get it to save the barcode pngs to the desired directory. It extracts the required data fine, but using the executable to save anything to a non-temporary file is proving difficult.
Is this possible using one file or is it best for me to use the default folder option? Or is there another option entirely that would work better than a PyInstaller executable?
I tried using --add-data when building the executable to include the excel sheets and barcode directory, but it seemed as if it made separate copies of those files upon building the executable. It doesn't notice any changes made to the data file and can't update the directory with new data. I was hoping that this would just allow the executable to access the desired data files and make the appropriate changes.
I also watched this Youtube video and it seemed to imply that all I didn't need to use --add-data at all and all I had to do was move the executable to the appropriate directory. I've tried this multiple times and it still doesn't update the folder with new barcode pngs. (I don't know if this is an older version of pyinstaller that has different capabilities?)
def main():

    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    else:
        base_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    
    inventory_path=os.path.join(base_path, 'sheets', 'Inventory.xlsm')
    print(inventory_path)

    #if not os.path.isfile(inventory_path):
    #    print(f"Error: the file {inventory_path} does not exist. :(")
    #    sys.exit(1)

    df = loadData("sheets/Inventory.xlsm")
    # Iterate through the rows in the DF
    SKU = df.apply(generateSKU, axis=1)
    print(SKU)
    df = df.assign(SKU=SKU)
    print(df)

    barcodes_path = os.path.join(base_path, 'sheets', 'Barcodes.xlsx')
    saveData(df, barcodes_path)

    barcode_dir = os.path.join(base_path, 'barcodes')

    if not os.path.exists(barcode_dir):
        os.makedirs(barcode_dir)
    
    for code in SKU:
        generateBarcode(code, barcode_dir)


This is my current main() function, I had to use the actual path name (sheets/Inventory.xlsm) to load the data because using inventory_path was not working. It would give the temporary location and couldn't find the spreadsheet. I also commented out the if statement for debugging purposes.

so what exactly is your question?

I guess I'm asking if a single file executable can save the barcode pngs to another folder? I'm struggling to have it save data to a directory that is not the temporary _MEI folders it creates.

if you define a path in your script to a path outside of the exe it does not work?
